# Question on smooth affine curves over finite fields and Hasse-Weil

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, curves

I don't have a strong background in algebraic geometry, so my question could seems trivial, but I would like to know more about it. So if you have a book to recomend, thanks in advance!

Suppose you have a curve $C: f(x,y)=0$ over a finite field $K$.

- Can I say that the affine curve $C$ is absolutely irreducible if it does not have singular points even if the homogenization of $C$ has singular points?
- Knowing that the curve is absolutely irreducible and smooth. Can I apply the Hasse-Weil bound to the number of rational points of the affine curve $C$?

Comment: Welcome new contributor. I've taken the liberty of adding some MathJax to your post to get your math formulas to display a little better. For more information on MathJax, see the tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Singularities can and sometimes will ruin your day. People have looked at what happens, when you allow them. Random googling gave me [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235637878_Weil_Theorem_for_Singular_curves). Don't know if that is A) accessible, B) useful in the cases that interest you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unfortunately, no. The curve determined by $f(x,y)=x(x-1)$ is smooth in the plane, singular at infinity, and not absolutely irreducible. For something that's a little less cheat-y, consider $f(x,y)=x^2+x+1$ over $\Bbb F_2$ - this is smooth in the plane, irreducible, but not absolutely irreducible, and has a singular point at infinity.
2. Unfortunately, no. Removing the points at infinity can cause the Hasse-Weil bound to malfunction. The easiest example is $f(x,y)=x$: this is a curve of genus zero, so Hasse-Weil says it should have exactly $q+1$ points. But it only has $q$ points.

Comment: Ok, then one need to homogenize the curve and prove that the homogeneous version is smooth. Supposing that the homogeneous one is not smooth, are there other ways to prove that it is absolutely irreducible?